# Every Field Extension is Composite of its finite subextensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, profinite-groups

In Page 279 of Algebriac Number Theory by Neukirch, it states that every field extension is composite of its finite subextensions. I know how to prove this in Galois Theory, but I don't see how to translate the proof to abstract Galois Theory.

In Neukrich, we take a profinite group $G$, and denote $G_K$ to be a closed subgroup of $G$ where we call $K$ as fix field of $G_K$. We say $L/K$ is a field extension if $G_L\subset G_K$. If $G_L$ is an open subgroup (equivalent to $G_L$ has finite index) in $G_K$, then we we say $L/K$ is a finite extension. The composite of $K_i$, denoted as $\prod_i K_i$ is the fix field of $\bigcap_i G_{K_i}$. So we need to prove that if $G_L\subset G_K$, then $$G_L = \bigcap_{G_L\subset G_M\subset G_K, [G_K: G_M]<\infty} G_M$$

I feel that this should be related to the topology on $G$ that there is open neighborhood basis of $1$ consisting of open subgroups of $G$.

Comment: Every algebraic element generates a finite extension. ${\mathbb Q}(\pi)/{\mathbb Q}$ shows that the extension must be algebraic.

Comment: I'm confused by your profinite set-up. What's the role of the ambient group $G$? Are you implicitly assuming it to operate on some field extension? This would probably be clearer if you called the Galois groups as such. In any case, a field extension is the composite of its finite subextensions if and only if it is algebraic, as franz lemmermeyer already commented, and this point really is elementary and not one of Galois theory.

Comment: Do you see why it’s true for every algebraic extension? In my view, this has nothing to do with the group aspect of Galois theory, rather it’s just field theory. And, in accordance with @franzlemmermeyer’s remark, do you see why it’s not true for any nonalgebraic extension?

Comment: @Lubin I know how to prove this for algebraic extension if we referring to the usual Field Theory. However, not every profinite group is Galois group of some field extension. So the $K, L$ are not necessarily some fields. They are just index of closed subgroups of $G$. So I am asking for a proof using purely groups and the topology on it.

Comment: Every profinite group is a Galois group of some field extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got an answer.

Since $G_K\supset G_L$ are closed subgroup of a profnite $G$, then we know that $G_K/G_L$ is again a profinite group. Then it suffice to show that the intersection of all open subgroup of a profinite group is $\{1\}$. This follows from open normal subgroups form a clopen neighborhood basis of $\{1\}$, and a profinite group is compact, Hausdorff and totally disconnected. Then the intersection of those open normal subgroups is the same as intersection of all clopen subsets containing $1$, and this equals the connected component containing $1$ which is $\{1\}$.